# Jackson + Builder Pattern?

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'd like Jackson to deserialize a class with the following constructor:

```
public Clinic(String name, Address address)
```

Deserializing the first argument is easy. The problem is that Address is defined as:

```
public class Address {
  private Address(Map<LocationType, String> components)
  ...

  public static class Builder {
    public Builder setCity(String value);
    public Builder setCountry(String value);
    public Address create();
  }
}
```

and is constructed like this: `new Address.Builder().setCity("foo").setCountry("bar").create();`

Is there a way to get key-value pairs from Jackson in order to construct the Address myself? Alternatively, is there a way to get Jackson to use the Builder class itself?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

As long as you are using Jackson 2+, then there is now [built in support for this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern).

First you need to add this annotation to your `Address` class:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Address.Builder.class)
```

Then you need to add this annotation to your `Builder` class:

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "create", withPrefix = "set")
```

You can skip this second annotation if you are happy to rename your Builder's create method to build, and your Builder's setters to be prefixed to with, instead of set.

Full example:

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Address.Builder.class)
public class Address
{
  private Address(Map<LocationType, String> components)
  ...

  @JsonPOJOBuilder(buildMethodName = "create", withPrefix = "set")
  public static class Builder
  {
    public Builder setCity(String value);
    public Builder setCountry(String value);
    public Address create();
  }
}
```

Comment: If it is desired to get rid of the `@JsonPOJOBuilder` annotation all together, rename "create" to "build" and annotate each of the builder setters with `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: this is golden. Thanks.

Comment: This is now outdated, with Lombok 1.18.4 you can use `@Jacksonized` which replaces the inner builder and the jackson annotations with a single thing

Comment: @Randakar I don't think this is outdated because a)  `@Jackonized`  is a just released experimental feature in Lombok. I don't think it is a good idea to unnecessarily encourage adoption of experimental features. b) the question doesn't mention or use Lombok. I don't think it is a good idea to unnecessarily introduce a dependency to solve a problem.

Comment: Fair enough. I was updating another answer with this information where lombok *was* relevant, apparently I cast too wide a net.

Answer (score 26):

The answer from @Rupert Madden-Abbott works. However, if you have a non-default constructor, e.g.,

```
Builder(String city, String country) {...}
```

Then you should annotate the parameters as below:

```
@JsonCreator
Builder(@JsonProperty("city")    String city, 
        @JsonProperty("country") String country) {...}
```

Answer (score 14):

A solution which was suitable for me in this case (I used "Lombok" builder annotation).

```
@Getter
@Builder(builderMethodName = "builder")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@JsonAutoDetect(
    fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY,
    creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY
)
```

I hope would be useful for u too.

Comment: This is now outdated, with Lombok 1.18.4 you can use `@Jacksonized` which replaces the inner builder and the jackson annotations with a single thing

Comment: But if you can't upgrade our library due to company rules. This is continue to working fine for me

Answer (score 7):

I ended up implementing this using the @JsonDeserialize as follows:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JacksonDeserializer.class)
public class Address
{...}

@JsonCachable
static class JacksonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Address>
{
    @Override
    public Address deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        JsonToken token = parser.getCurrentToken();
        if (token != JsonToken.START_OBJECT)
        {
            throw new JsonMappingException("Expected START_OBJECT: " + token, parser.getCurrentLocation());
        }
        token = parser.nextToken();
        Builder result = new Builder();
        while (token != JsonToken.END_OBJECT)
        {
            if (token != JsonToken.FIELD_NAME)
            {
                throw new JsonMappingException("Expected FIELD_NAME: " + token, parser.getCurrentLocation());
            }
            LocationType key = LocationType.valueOf(parser.getText());

            token = parser.nextToken();
            if (token != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)
            {
                throw new JsonMappingException("Expected VALUE_STRING: " + token, parser.getCurrentLocation());
            }
            String value = parser.getText();

            // Our Builder allows passing key-value pairs
            // alongside the normal setter methods.
            result.put(key, value);
            token = parser.nextToken();
        }
        return result.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be how you ended up implementing it, but this answer doesn't actually answer the question as posed.  The answer posted by @Rupert Madden-Abbott should be marked as the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me: @NoArgsConstructor
The only drawback of this, is that one can do = new ADTO() again.
But, hey, I dont like de code police anyhow, telling me how to use someones code :-)
So, use my POJO DTOS the way you like it. With or without builder. I suggest: do it with a Builder, but be my guest...

```
@Data
@Builder
//Dont forget this! Otherwise no Jackson serialisation possible!
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ADTO {
.....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no support currently for builder pattern, although it has been requested quite a while ago (and finally Jira issue http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-469 was filed) -- it is something that may be added for 1.8 release if there is enough demand (make sure to vote at Jira!). It is a reasonable additional feature, and only delayed by amount of time developers have. But I think it would be great addition.

Comment: Codehaus no longer has Jira available but the linked issue is described here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern

Comment: Support for Builder pattern has been long since added, at something like Jackson 2.2.