# Jackson Builder with method to create builder

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to use Jackson to deserialize Json, where I have a builder that creates my objects.  This is similar to [Jackson + Builder Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982340/jackson-builder-pattern).  However, to create my builder, I need to do  `MyObject.builder()`, as the `builder` method does additional initialization beyond that done in the constructor.

The documentation at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBuilderPattern seems to only allow changing the prefix to the method names for setting values and the method name that creates the final object.