# How to use Jackson to deserialize external Lombok builder class

Tags: java, jackson, mixins, builder, lombok

I have a 3rd party Lombok builder POJO, one that I cannot modify, that I want to serialize using jackson. Notably it does *not* have a NoArgsConstructor.

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ExternalClass {
   private String name;
   private String data; 
   // etc.
}
```

On the surface this would appear to be simple, but it is incredibly frustrating in practice as each possible option seems to be counteracted by a different complication. In essence, I'm having trouble getting an **external** Lombok **builder** to work with a jackson **mixin**.

Lombok produces fluent setters of the style `.name(String name)` while Jackson's built-in builder deserializer expects `.withName(String name)`. Lombok documentation, and recipes elsewhere such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982340/jackson-builder-pattern) suggest using `@JsonDeserialize(builder=ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder.class)` in conjunction with `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")` on a predeclared inner stub builder. But this is not possible because the Lombok class is in an external library.

Applying these annotations to a mixin has no effect.

```
@JsonDeserialize(ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder.class)
public abstract class ExternalClassMixin {
   @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
   public static ExternalClassBuilder {
   }
}
```

The only approach I've found that works is to leverage the package-access AllArgsConstructor created by `@Builder` and populate the mixin with the following constructor

```
public abstract class ExternalClassMixin {
   @JsonCreator public ExternalClassMixin(
      @JsonProperty("name") String name,
      @JsonProperty("data") String data,
      // etc.
  ) {} 
}
```

This is obviously not desirable as it requires iterating and hard-coding every class property explicitly, making the mixin fragile to any change in the external POJO.

My question is - is there a robust, maintainable way to serialize this external builder class using Jackson without modifying it, using either a mixin or maybe a full blown deserializer?

**Update**

I implemented the excellent answer by @jan-rieke, including the suggestion to use reflection to seek out the inner builder class.

```
...
public Class<?> findPOJOBuilder(AnnotatedClass ac) {
   Class<?> innerBuilder;
   try {
      innerBuilder = Class.forName(ac.getName()+"$"+ac.getRawType().getSimpleName()+"Builder");
      log.info("Builder found: {}", ac.getName());
      return innerBuilder;
   } catch( ClassNotFoundException e ) {
      return super.findPOJOBuilder(ac);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your question solved my issue. I have access to the external lombok builder which is used by JTwig to generate API Clients. I could add the annotations `@JsonDeserialize` and `@JsonPOJOBuilder` to the template. If you make an answer out of that, I'll reward you with a bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize your `ObjectMapper` as follows:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        @Override
        public Class<?> findPOJOBuilder(AnnotatedClass ac) {
            if (ExternalClass.class.equals(ac.getRawType())) {
                return ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder.class;
            }
            return super.findPOJOBuilder(ac);
        }

        @Override
        public Value findPOJOBuilderConfig(AnnotatedClass ac) {
            if (ac.hasAnnotation(JsonPOJOBuilder.class)) {
                return super.findPOJOBuilderConfig(ac);
            }
            return new JsonPOJOBuilder.Value("build", "");
        }
    });
```

This will

- explicitly configure that deserialization for `ExternalClass` uses its builder, and
- set the default prefix for builder setter methods to `""` (except when the `@JsonPOJOBuilder` annotation is present).

If you do not want to list all external classes explicitly in `findPOJOBuilder()`, you can of course programmatically look into the class to check whether it has a inner class that looks like a builder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked and I followed your recommendation to replace the hardcoded class names with a generalized solution.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by creating two mixins: one for `ExternalClass` (specifying the builder to use) and one for `ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder` (specifying the lack of a prefix in the builder methods).

```java
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder.class)
public interface ExternalClassMixin {
}

@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix="")
public interface ExternalClassBuilderMixin {
}
```

This serializes and deserializes the JSON in the desired manner:

```java
String json = "{\"name\": \"The Name\", \"data\": \"The Data\"}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .addMixIn(ExternalClass.class, ExternalClassMixin.class)
        .addMixIn(ExternalClass.ExternalClassBuilder.class, ExternalClassBuilderMixin.class);

System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, ExternalClass.class));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.readValue(json, ExternalClass.class)));
```

Output:

```
ExternalClass(name=The Name, data=The Data)
{"name":"The Name","data":"The Data"}
```